# Initializing empty Python data structures

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there any tangible difference between the two forms of syntax available for creating empty Python lists/dictionaries, i.e.

```
l = list()
l = []
```

and:

```
d = dict()
d = {}
```

I'm wondering if using one is preferable over the other.

Comment: `[]` and `{}` are faster and look better in my opinion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function form calls the constructor at runtime to return a new instance, whereas the literal form causes the compiler to "create" it (really, to emit bytecode that results in a new object) at compile time. The former can be useful if (for some reason) the classes have been locally rebound to different types.

```
>>> def f():
...   []
...   list()
...   {}
...   dict()
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 POP_TOP             

  3           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              7 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             10 POP_TOP             

  4          11 BUILD_MAP                0
             14 POP_TOP             

  5          15 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (dict)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             21 POP_TOP             
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: A fun side effect of this is that if you're writing a small function that needs to cache some data between calls (perhaps a simple memoizer), you can say `def f(a, b, cache={}):` and the dict created will actually persist between calls to `f()`

Comment: @Robru: This is unrelated.  Using `def f(a, b, cache=dict())` also works.

Comment: FWIW, for non-empty instances, the function form may be more flexible because it may support multiple ways of specifying the object's contents, such as is the case with `dict`.

Comment: [How should I understand the output of dis.dis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673074/how-should-i-understand-the-output-of-dis-dis)

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is that one form includes a name lookup, while the other doesn't.  Example illustrating this difference:

```
def list():
    return {}

print []
print list()
```

prints

```
[]
{}
```

Of course you definitely should not be doing such nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

My gut tells me that both are acceptable, so long as you're consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any difference, would be mostly a stylistic preference.