# How to time disassembled representation of a Python code source

Tags: python

So far, when I want to inspect what might cause some sort of code to run faster compared to a very similar method, I'm using the `dis` module. However, the further steps of comparing what the causes is basically adding/removing lines.

Is there a more sophisticated way of actually listing what the high-offenders are?

Comment: Related: [How does one use `dis.dis` to analyze performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19322705/190597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of code do you want to analyze? If you want to analyze pure python code. You can use `profile`. For example:

```
import cProfile

cProfile.run("x=1")
```

Or you can run a function: `cProfile.run("function()")`

Then it will show you something like the following:

```
         4 function calls in 0.013 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.013    0.013    0.013    0.013 <ipython-input-7-8201fb940887>:1(fun)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.013    0.013 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.013    0.013 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: How do you get 0.013 seconds on `x=1` ?

Comment: @user1767754 The result I showed is from another function with a large loop inside.