# How to read python bytecode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bytecode

I am having a lot of difficulty understanding Python's bytecode and its `dis` module.

```
import dis
def func():
   x = 1
dis.dis(func)
```

The above code when typed in the interpreter produces the following output:

```
    0 LOAD_CONST                  1(1)
    3 STORE_FAST                  0(x)
    6 LOAD_CONST                  0(NONE)
    9 RETURN_VALUE
```

**E.g.:**

What is the meaning of `LOAD_CONST`, `STORE_FAST` and the numbers like `0`, `3`, `6` and `9`?

A specific resource, where I can find this information would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if you read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12673195/973699

Comment: @DevC I read this question, but the problem was that I just wanted a explanation for a very "simple" function, just like the one I mentioned in my question, so that I could at least get a slight idea of what exactly is happening in the byte code.

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673074/how-should-i-understand-the-output-of-dis-dis

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The numbers before the bytecodes are offsets into the original binary bytecodes:

```
>>> func.__code__.co_code
'd\x01\x00}\x00\x00d\x00\x00S'
```

Some bytecodes come with additional information (arguments) that influence how each bytecode works, the offset tells you at what position in the bytestream the bytecode was found.

The `LOAD_CONST` bytecode (ASCII `d`, hex 64) is followed by two additional bytes encoding a reference to a constant associated with the bytecode, for example. As a result, the `STORE_FAST` opcode (ASCII `}`, hex 7D) is found at index 3.

The [`dis` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions) lists what each instruction means. For `LOAD_CONST`, it says:

> Pushes `co_consts[consti]` onto the stack.

which refers to the `co_consts` structure that is always present with a code object; the compiler constructs that:

```
>>> func.__code__.co_consts
(None, 1)
```

The opcode loads index 1 from that structure (the 01 00 bytes in the bytecode encode a 1), and `dis` has looked that up for you; it is the value `1`.

The next instruction, [`STORE_FAST`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST) is described as:

> Stores TOS into the local `co_varnames[var_num]`.

Here *TOS* refers to Top Of Stack; note that the `LOAD_CONST` just *pushed* something onto the stack, the `1` value. `co_varnames` is another structure; it references local variable names, the opcode references index 0:

```
>>> func.__code__.co_varnames
('x',)
```

`dis` looked that up too, and the name you used in your code is `x`. Thus, this opcode stored `1` into `x`.

Another `LOAD_CONST` loads `None` onto the stack from index 0, followed by [`RETURN_VALUE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-RETURN_VALUE):

> Returns with TOS to the caller of the function.

so this instruction takes the top of the stack (with the `None` constant) and returns from this code block. `None` is the default return value for functions without an explicit `return` statement.

You omitted something from the `dis` output, the line numbers:

```
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the `2` on the first line; that's the line number in the original source that contains the Python code that was used for these instructions. Python code objects have `co_lnotab` and `co_firstlineno` attributes that let you map bytecodes back to line numbers in the original source. `dis` does this for you when displaying a disassembly.

Comment: thanks for the extensive answer and the reference to the docs