# What is the difference between the following two statements?

Tags: python

```
x = func(*(xa,) + args)
y = func(*((xc,) + args))
```

where args is an array and function definition is:

```
def func(lamb, data):
    # statements
```

I learnt about `*args`, but I couldn't find the exact difference between these lines.

Comment: an extra set of brackets.  Thats it, there is no difference in execution, the byte code is identical: `dis.dis("func(*(xa,) + args)")` gives the exact same operations as `dis.dis("func(*((xc,) + args))")`

Comment: also the first uses `xa` while the second uses  `xc` ;)

Comment: If the function you are trying to call takes two arguments and you want to pass it two arguments why are you using the `*args` mechanic at all? Don't you want to just do `func(xa, args)` ?

Comment: I am pretty new to Python. I amn't writing, just trying to understand a source code @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is the extra set of brackets and one uses `xa` while the other uses `xc`, but even that doesn't make much of a difference [to the byte code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis), take a look:

```
# python 2 needs to use dis.dis(compile("func(*(xa,)+args)","","eval"))
# to get same result, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673074/how-should-i-understand-the-output-of-dis-dis
>>> dis.dis("func(*(xa,)+args)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (func)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (xa)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_NAME                2 (args)
             12 BINARY_ADD
             13 CALL_FUNCTION_VAR        0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("func(*((xc,)+args))")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (func)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (xc)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_NAME                2 (args)
             12 BINARY_ADD
             13 CALL_FUNCTION_VAR        0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is a simple matter of [precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precedence), the addition takes priority over the `*` unpacking (CALL_FUNCTION_VAR is the exact bytecode used) so adding brackets doesn't change anything, much like here:

```
3 * 5 + 1
```

The multiplication will happen first so adding brackets around it:

```
(3 * 5) + 1
```

Doesn't change what is going to happen.

---

Also note that you don't have to add tuples together when unpacking arguments, you can just as easily do:

```
func(xa, *args)
```

to accomplish the same result without having to add tuples together (and this will work when `args` is something other then a tuple where as your version would raise a TypeError)