# What is the dis function doing when I pass in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, bytecode

The [`dis.dis()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis) function in the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module allows one to disassemble raw bytecode from a code object into a human-readable form. The documentation for `dis()` states what may be passed into the function:

> Disassemble the `bytesource` object. `bytesource` **can denote either a module, a class, a method, a function, or a code object**. For a module, it disassembles all functions. For a class, it disassembles all methods. For a single code sequence, it prints one line per bytecode instruction. If no object is provided, it disassembles the last traceback.

When experimenting with the module, everything works as expected. However I was surprised when I passed a `str` object into function and it ran fine:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('1 + 2')
          0 <49>           
          1 SLICE+2        
          2 STORE_SLICE+3  
          3 SLICE+2        
          4 DELETE_SLICE+0 
>>>
```

The documentation for `dis()` *specifically* said what was allowed to be passed to the function. And the last time I checked, a `str` does not satisfy any of those requirements. [Per the documentation for code objects](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#index-59):

> Code objects represent byte-compiled executable Python code, or bytecode. [...]

But what surprised me even more, was the *bytecode* that `dis()` has generated. What does this bytecode mean? I decied to check and see what each opcode meant by looking at *[32.12.1. Python Bytecode Instructions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions)* on the documentation page for `dis`. This however confused me even more. Some opcodes were not even documented(`<49>`).

What exactly is Python trying to do with the string I passed in. Is it considering my string to be literal source code? Or is attempting to construct a string from what I've passed in?

I would assume my former guess to be correct, due to [looking over the source code for `dis.disassemble_string()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/dis.py#l110)(Which is what`dis.dis()` calls when a `str` object is passed in). But if that is true, then why does the bytecode look so strange? If I pass in a function with the same expression, the bytecode makes perfect sense:

```
>>> def func():
...     1 + 2
... 
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              3 POP_TOP             
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

This behavior doesn't seem to be limited to expression, though. I tried several other statements, and they all generated the same weird-looking bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis('foo = 10')
          0 BUILD_TUPLE     28527
          3 SLICE+2        
          4 DELETE_SUBSCR  
          5 SLICE+2        
          6 <49>           
          7 <48>           
>>> dis.dis('print 0')
          0 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP 26994
          3 JUMP_FORWARD     8308 (to 8314)
          6 <48>           
>>> # etc...
```

Is this behavior documented somewhere? I looked over the entire documentation page for the `dis` module, but I didn't find any relevant information.

Comment: in python 2 there is no distinction between "character string" and "bytestring" so it is trying to interpret your words as python bytecode

Comment: the `<49>` is coming from `ord('1')`, it doesn't mean anything as a bytecode command so dis displays it like that to indicate "what ever this byte is"

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The question you linked to _could_ be a duplicate, but I believe the question asker is asking about a very specfic case. And the selected answer given is more about trying to help solve the OP's specfic case, rather than explaining why he is having a problem. My question is more of a general case.

Comment: I'm sorry I marked the wrong one, I think I meant to use [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673074/how-should-i-understand-the-output-of-dis-dis) as the duplicate target, my bad.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Now that duplicate helped ;) I'll mark my question as a dupe now.

Comment: That is indeed a closely related question, but I don't think it's quite a duplicate. I think it'd be good to post an answer to this question that references the other one.

Comment: @DavidZ _Whooooopsie!_ I guess I was a little to hasty.....

Comment: Eh, no big deal. At least people coming across this later will find the information they need!

Comment: The biggest thing that my [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205848/what-is-the-dis-function-doing-when-i-pass-in-a-string?noredirect=1#comment69610945_41205848) may not explain well enough is that bytecode in python2 is a string, I.E. `type(compile("1+2","","eval").co_code)  == <type 'str'>` so it does satisfy one of the argument accepted. (in python 3 bytecode is type `bytes` so there isn't the same ambiguity)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Got you. Thanks for explanations.